# How to return a response and then redirect in nedb?

Tags: node.js, express, nedb

My code, in short, is

```
res.status(200).end();
return res.redirect("/");
```

but this gives an error saying `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to remove the `.end` in `res.status`:

```
res.status(200);
return res.redirect("/");
```